# About a Kafka Producer with Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm new to kafka. When i try to send a message through a producer this error pops up. Can anyone tell what is the problem for that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pls don't post your code as images. See [idownvotedyoubecause](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

Jackson missing classes is a bug in Kafka 2.6.0

You can downgrade to the most recent 2.5 client version if a newer version is not available yet